# Convert Objective-C code snippet to detect Jailbreak bypass tweaks to Xamarin (C#)

Tags: c#, objective-c, xamarin, xamarin.ios

My Xamarin based iOS application should not run in jailbroken devices. This is due to a IS audit. For audit purpose I have to implement a method to detect jailbroken status. I have implemented the jailbroken detect mechanism. But I cannot find a way to detect whether someone using a jailbroken bypass method like for example A-bypass, shadow tweaks. Then I got some code snippet in Objective-C from the audit team. I tried with binding library (Sharpie). But got more than 3000 errors in my Xamarin project. I have zero experience in Objective-C. Is there any way of transform this to C#?

```
    NSInteger kernel_value = test();

    if(kernel_value != 2147483650){
        exit(1);

    }else{

        [super viewDidLoad];
        NSLog(@"Display Int Value kernel_value : %li",kernel_value);

     }

 

uint32_t test() {
    char* filename = "/var/lib/dpkg/status"; // Checking this file to find jailbreak detection
    volatile uint32_t result = -1;
    
    volatile uint64_t nzcv = 0;
    
#if __arm64__           //inline assembly code
    
    __asm volatile (
                  "mov x0, %[file] \n"
                  "mov x1, 0 \n"
                  "mov x16, #5 \n"
                  "svc #42 \n"
                  "mov %w[res], w0 \n"
                  "mrs %[c], nzcv"
                  : [res] "=r"(result), [c] "=r"(nzcv)
                   : [file] "r"(filename)
                   : "x0", "x1", "x16", "memory", "cc"
                   );
 #endif
     
    uint32_t cc = (nzcv >> 29) & 1;
     return result | (cc << 31);
 }
```

**UPDATE after Kyle Wang's answer**

```
//  TweakCheck.h
//  TweakCheck

#import <Foundation/Foundation.h>

@interface TweakCheck : NSObject

-(uint32_t)checkMethod;

@end
```

---

```
//  TweakCheck.m
//  TweakCheck

#import "TweakCheck.h"

@implementation TweakCheck

-(uint32_t)checkMethod {  

  char* filename = "/var/lib/dpkg/status"; // Checking this file to find jailbreak

  volatile uint32_t result = -1;

  volatile uint64_t nzcv = 0;
  

#if __arm64__           //inline assembly code

  __asm volatile (

                "mov x0, %[file] \n"

                "mov x1, 0 \n"

                "mov x16, #5 \n"

                "svc #42 \n"

                "mov %w[res], w0 \n"

                "mrs %[c], nzcv"

                : [res] "=r"(result), [c] "=r"(nzcv)

                : [file] "r"(filename)

                : "x0", "x1", "x16", "memory", "cc"

                );

#endif

  uint32_t cc = (nzcv >> 29) & 1;

  return result | (cc << 31);

}

@end
```

*If I am not limit the scope of the binding, using -scope then ApiDefinition.cs file and Structs.cs file getting too large and also giving me 3000+ errors in Xamarin side. If I use -scope then Structs.cs not creating.

After using sharpie, ApiDefinision.cs file

```
using System;
using CoreFoundation;
using Foundation;
using ObjCRuntime;
using Security;

namespace NativeLibrary

{

    // @interface TweakCheck : NSObject

    [BaseType(typeof(NSObject))]

    interface TweakCheck

    {

        // -(uint32_t)checkMethod;

        [Export("checkMethod")]

        uint CheckMethod { get; }

    }

}
```

Comment: I don't think you can inline assembly code like this in C#. However, you could create a small binding library around this small piece of code. It shouldn't take much effort to do so.

Comment: I have no idea on objective-c. Where should I put this code. There are two files name.h and name.m in xcode project. There is @interface inside name.h . should I put inside it this?

Comment: I know about C#. I wanna know how and where should I put above objective-C code? inside .h or .m in Xcode static library project? cause as @Cheesebaron said I have create a binding library.

Comment: In .h, you need to write the declaration of the filed, property and method. `@interface MyClass:NSObject -(void)TestMethod @end` Then all the logic goes in .m.`@implementation MyClass -(void)TestMethod{// logic here} @end`

Comment: thank you @KyleWang. I have done as you said. then I created a binding library. But I cannot call to the objective-c function. can you tell me whether it is correct or not? I will update the question.

Comment: Did you add the native library to the project, i.e., the .a file? Here is the the guide for [Binding Objective-C libraries](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/xamarin/cross-platform/macios/binding/objective-c-libraries?context=xamarin%2Fios&tabs=macos).

Comment: @KyleWang yes i did and also change the build action

Comment: "checkMethod" is a method, but you declare it as a property "uint CheckMethod { get; }" in C#.

Comment: that is given by the objective sharpie after doing **sharpie bind -output Binding -sdk iphoneos14.1 -scope /Users/ictsoftware/Desktop/cus/TweakCheck/TweakCheck  /Users/ictsoftware/Desktop/cus/TweakCheck/TweakCheck/TweakCheck.h ;**